# Glassfish+NetBeans: Why does JSF Web App as presentation module need to reference both EJB API module and EJB implementation module

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, java-ee-7

Glassfish4.1.1 (or Payara41)
Java EE 7

*[EDIT: The simple answer/solution might be "don't do it that way, use an EAR instead", but it has some disadvantages, see bottom]*

---

I am exploring strategies for modularising a large web app. I have the following structure under a folder /multi-ant (noting all of the project modules are NetBeans Ant-style project versions):

```
multi-ant/
├── CoreAPIAnt       (NetBeans Java Class Library project)
├── CoreEJBAnt       (NetBeans EJB Module project)
├── CoreWebAnt       (NetBeans Web Application Project, WAR + extra JAR build)
```

The system (as shown here) uses only @Local interfaces (there is also a @Remote aspect and standalone app client not shown).

CoreWebAnt can run standalone as a JSF Web App with WAR structure.

In CoreEJBAnt I have a single Element entity and:

```
@Stateless
public class ElementQuery implements IElementQuery {
```

Where IElementQuery is in CoreAPIAnt, which is a NetBeans Java Class Library project:

```
@Local
public interface IElementQuery extends Serializable {
```

In the CoreWebAnt JSF web app I have:

```
...
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

@Named(value = "elementManager")
@ViewScoped
public class ElementManager implements Serializable {

    @EJB private IElementQuery elementQuery;
```

The aim is to have the web app modules EJB-implementation agnostic, but if I just set CoreAPIAnt as a project dependency (dist/CoreAPIAnt.jar) in CoreWebAnt (without reference to dist/CoreEJBAnt.jar) and then deploy CoreEJBAnt and the CoreWebAnt, the ElementManager used in CoreWebAnt can't resolve the injection against IElementQuery and I get this error:

```
Severe:   Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=com.example.multi.core.web.ElementManager/elementQuery,Local 3.x interface =com.example.multi.core.api.IElementQuery,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [CoreWebAnt]
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=com.example.multi.core.web.ElementManager/elementQuery,Local 3.x interface =com.example.multi.core.api.IElementQuery,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ComponentValidator.accept(ComponentValidator.java:374)
```

If I however **also** include CoreEJBAnt as a project dependency in CoreWebAnt (so dist/CoreEJBAnt.jar is available under its /lib) I can run CoreWebAnt fine completely standalone (and without first deploying CoreEJBAnt). **But this defeats the entire purpose of having the interface-only CoreAPIAnt module.**

*Q: Why can't Glassfish "see" and resolve the injection implementation candidate @Stateless ElementQuery in the deployed CoreEJBAnt (vs @EJB IElementQuery from CoreAPIAnt used in CoreWebAnt) when CoreWebAnt is run separately and only dependent on CoreAPIAnt.jar ?*

I wish if possible to avoid the overhead of @Remote (and all of the consequences of entities returned over RMI) and stay completely in a @Local development ecosystem for now.

Having to reference the CoreEJBAnt module from the web app(s) is not the end of the world, but it breaks the vs-API rule and I'd like to understand why it's also needed here.

---

**EDIT: EAR approach (after more investigation)**

If I create an empty EAR project in NetBeans (without a nested EJB module or Web App module), I can then use **Add Java EE module** on the **Java EE Modules** node to add CoreEJBAnt.jar and CoreWebAnt.war, and it runs fine without the CoreWebAnt module having a project dependency on the implementation module CoreEJBAnt (it just needs CoreAPIAnt). The exploded distribution structure is then like:

```
$ tree -L 3 CoreEAR/dist/gfdeploy/
CoreEAR/dist/gfdeploy/
└── CoreEAR
    ├── CoreEJBAnt_jar
    │   ├── CoreAPIAnt.jar
    │   ├── META-INF
    │   ├── com ...
    │   └── rebel.xml
    ├── CoreWebAnt_war
    │   ├── META-INF
    │   ├── WEB-INF
    │   ├── index.xhtml
    │   └── resources
    ├── META-INF
    │   └── MANIFEST.MF
    ├── gfv3ee6.dpf
    ├── lib
    │   ├── CoreAPIAnt.jar
    │   └── other.jar
```

It even nicely pulls in other JAR libraries under lib I was also having to put in the lib of CoreWebAnt to get it to run standalone.

However, I then get some new errors when using JRebel, although it is definitely catching and hot reloading changes in edits in the CoreWebAnt and CoreEJBAnt projects.

*So the answer to my question may indeed by "don't try to use the standalone web app, use the EAR approach", but I am still interested in knowing why Glassfish is not designed to let a web app "see" the separately deployed EJB module. I did not find anything specific about it in the specs.*

Comment: Tried JBoss Wildfly just to see if it maybe is implementation related?

Comment: @Kukeltje Not tried Wildfly yet, but it's a good idea. I think the problem has to do with Classloader separation, and it may behave differently in different server container implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Java™ Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) Specification, v7** provides a clear description of the requirements for runtime class visibility in the **Application Assembly and Deployment** section.

This is what all complete Java EE servers such as GlassFish and WildFly implement.

The isolation of separately deployed components (deployment units) is deliberate.

Comment: Thanks, answer indeed at least implied by Java™ Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) Specification v7 section **EE.8.3Class Loading Requirements**. The message is to use EAR, however it also warns: "Components in the web container may have access to the following classes and resources. Portable applications _must not depend on having or not having access to these classes or resources_: ... The content of any EJB jar files included in the same ear file."